# can't get apply_filter to work in wordpress thematic

Tags: wordpress, filter

I am learninig to create templates in wordpress using the thematic framework

In the header file I find:

```
 // Filter provided for altering output of the header opening element
    echo ( apply_filters( 'thematic_open_header',  '<div id="header">' ) );

   // Action hook creating the theme header
   thematic_header();

    echo ( apply_filters( 'thematic_close_header', '</div><!-- #header-->' ) );
```

I want to add a wrapper div element around the div id="header".../div created above

I have tried to edit the apply_filter lines like this:

```
echo ( apply_filters( 'thematic_open_header',  '<div id="headerWrapper"><div id="header">' ) );
```

but it doesn't work, just printout out div id="header"

How can I get it to create the html that I want it to?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filters are used in `functions.php` or in a plugin like this:

```
add_filter( 'thematic_open_header', function(){
    return '<div id="headerWrapper"><div id="header">';
});
```

The basic difference between `apply_filters` and `do_action` is that the first *filters* some value and returns something, while `add_action` will be used to do anything you want with the parameters sent or output something to the browser.

Some articles of interest: [[1]](http://themeshaper.com/2009/05/03/filters-wordpress-child-themes/), [[2]](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-actions-and-filters--wp-27373), [[3]](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/02/16/inside-wordpress-actions-filters/) and [[4]](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/definitive-guide-wordpress-hooks/).